# Vertically align first line in tcolorbox with surrounding text (e.g. enumerate label)

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, tcolorbox

Combining lists and text wrapping around figures is a hassle. The `wrapfig` package, for example, cannot do it. I am now trying to use a `\tcbsidebyside` box with `blanker` option to achieve it.

The question is: Is there a clean way to exactly align the baseline of the first line on the left-hand side to the surrounding baseline? In the MNWE below, I would like to get the first line inside the box to align with `enumerate` label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item \tcbsidebyside[blanker, sidebyside adapt=right,
    halign upper=justify, halign lower=right, 
    sidebyside align=top seam]{\blindtext}{<Some image>}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should rather use something like `\tcbitemize`

Comment: I don't see how this would help me. – I would like to get a wrapped figure inside a list, rather than a list inside a box.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the plain TeX macro package `insbox` and the `enumitem` package: the latter lets  you define the `right margin` of the list, and has a `stop and resume` functionality. The former defines `\InsertBoxL` and `\InsertBoxR` commands, which take two mandatory arguments: the number of untouched lines at the beginning of the following paragraph, before the box is inserted, and the object to be inserted. In addition an optional argument (to be given at the end) is the number of supplementary shorter lines, in case TeX computes a wrong number of short lines.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\input{insbox}

\begin{document}

\InsertBoxR{4}{\fboxsep = 0pt\fbox{\includegraphics[width = 4cm]{lepursuit1}}}
\begin{enumerate}[rightmargin =4.5cm]
  \item First item
  \item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
  \item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this seems like quite a manual hack. I was hoping for a more elegant and generic solution...